# abstract type pattern is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure

Tags: scala

Could someone tell me how can I avoid the warning in the code block below:

```
abstract class Foo[T <: Bar]{
  case class CaseClass[T <: Bar](t: T)
  def method1 = {
    case CaseClass(t: T) => println(t)
    csse _ => 
  }
}
```

This results in a compiler warning:

```
 abstract type pattern T is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
 case CaseClass(t: T) => println(t)
                   ^
```

Comment: what does `T <: Bar` mean on line 1?

Comment: It just means that the type of argument t is bounded above by T. Or in  other words T is a sub-type of Bar or Bar itself.

Comment: No, it means that the type of `t` is not guaranteed to be `T` at runtime, since the JVM performs type erasure (discards the type information).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could use `ClassTag` (or `TypeTag`):

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

abstract class Foo[T <: Bar : ClassTag]{
  ...
  val clazz = implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass
  def method1 = {
    case CaseClass(t) if clazz.isInstance(t) => println(t) // you could use `t.asInstanceOf[T]`
    case _ => 
  }
}
```

Comment: What does classtag do here?

Comment: Assuming you mean `ClassTag` in the class parameter signature, it tells the compiler to create an implicit `ClassTag[T]` parameter for the class, which is then accessed via `implicitly[ClassTag[T]]`. `abstract class Foo[T: ClassTag]` is sugar for `abstract class Foo[T](implicit tag: ClassTag[T])`

Answer (score 3):

Another variation to use, especially if you desire to use a `trait` (as opposed to using a `class` or `abstract class` which the other solution requires), looks like this:

```
import scala.reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}

trait Foo[B <: Bar] {
  implicit val classTagB: ClassTag[B] = classTag[B]
  ...
  def operate(barDescendant: B) =
    barDescendant match {
      case b: Bar if classTagB.runtimeClass.isInstance(b) =>
        ... //do something with value b which will be of type B
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I needed this in a trait and couldn't quite get to the implicit version. Cheers.