# Scala: abstract type pattern A is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure

Tags: scala, generics, functional-programming, type-erasure, scala-template

I am writing the function that can catch exceptions of the certain type only.

```
def myFunc[A <: Exception]() {
    try {
        println("Hello world") // or something else
    } catch {
        case a: A => // warning: abstract type pattern A is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
    }
}
```

What is the corrent way to bypass jvm type erasure in such case?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use `ClassTag` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18136667/406435).

But I'd prefer this approach:

```
def myFunc(recover: PartialFunction[Throwable, Unit]): Unit = {
  try {
    println("Hello world") // or something else
  } catch {
    recover
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
myFunc{ case _: MyException => }
```

Using `ClassTag`:

```
import scala.reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}

def myFunc[A <: Exception: ClassTag](): Unit = {
  try {
    println("Hello world") // or something else
  } catch {
    case a if classTag[A].runtimeClass.isInstance(a) =>
  }
}
```

Note also that in general you should use `Try` with `recover` method: `Try` will catch only [`NonFatal`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.control.NonFatal$) exceptions.

```
def myFunc(recover: PartialFunction[Throwable, Unit]) = {
  Try {
    println("Hello world") // or something else
  } recover {
    recover
  }.get // you could drop .get here to return `Try[Unit]`
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For every type check (e.g. `case a: A`) the JVM needs the corresponding `class` object to perform the check.  In your case the JVM does not have the class object, because `A` is a variable type parameter.  However, you can add additional information about `A` by implicitly passing a `Manifest[A]` to `myFunc`.  As a shorthand you can just add `: Manifest` to your type declaration of `A`:

```
def myFunc[A <: Exception : Manifest]() {
    try {
        println("Hello world") // or something else
    } catch {
        case a: A => // warning: abstract type pattern A is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
    }
}
```