# scala spark check fields dataType

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I just want to check a data frame's filed type, so I had to write this function;

```
import scala.refelect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def colCheck[T:TypeTag](data:DataFrame,colName:String):Boolean={
data.schema.exists(f->f.name==colName&f.dataType.isInstanceOf[T]
}
```

eg:data.schema.head is `StringType` and name is `col1`

I do this used spark-shell

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType,StringType}

val data:DataFrame=spark.createDataFrame(List(("",1),("",2))).toDF("col1","col2")



data.schema.head.dataType.isInstanceOf[StringType]

> :Boolean =true  # write result


data.schema.head.dataType.isInstanceOf[IntegerType]

> :Boolean =false    # write result

colChek[IntegerType](data,"col1")

> :Boolean =true
```

my expected is

```
colChek[IntegerType](data,"col1")

> :Boolean =false

colChek[StringType](data,"col1")

> :Boolean =false
```

but I got this

```
colChek[IntegerType](data,"col1")

> :Boolean =true
```

what causes this to happen and how to fix it, thanks very much

version
spark2.4.5
scala's version is 2.11.12

Comment: Could you specify what is the issue and what is the output you are expecting

Comment: I have updated my question, thanks very much

Answer (score 3):

You need to avoid type erasure as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180973/scala-abstract-type-pattern-a-is-unchecked-since-it-is-eliminated-by-erasure):

```
import scala.reflect.{classTag, ClassTag}
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataType, IntegerType, StringType}

def colCheck[T: ClassTag](data: DataFrame, colName: String): Boolean = {
    data.schema.exists(
        f => f.name == colName & classTag[T].runtimeClass.isInstance(f.dataType)
    )
}

val data: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(List(("",1),("",2))).toDF("col1","col2")

colCheck[IntegerType](data, "col1")   // false
colCheck[IntegerType](data, "col2")   // true
colCheck[StringType](data, "col1")    // true
colCheck[StringType](data, "col2")    // false
```

Comment: it worked ,what if ArrayType check ,it'only worked for `colCheck[ArrayTyep](data,"cola")`,what if i need  check  specify type `colCheck[ArrayType(IntegerType,false)](data,"cola")`

Comment: @SummersKing then you can use the other answer

Answer (score 3):

You should just pass in `IntegerType` as a value parameter instead of a type parameter, and then use `==` to compare instead of `isInstanceOf`.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType

def colCheck(data: DataFrame, colName: String, tpe: DataType): Boolean =
  Option(data.schema(colName)).exists(_.dataType == tpe)
```

```scala
colCheck(df, "col1", IntegerType)
```