# How to downcast with reflection in Scala?

Tags: scala, reflection

Suppose I have a non-sealed trait `A` and need a function `convert[T <: A]: A => Option[T]`:

```
def convert[T <: A](a: A): Option[T] = // don't compile
  if (a is instance of T) then Some(a) else None
```

How would you suggest implement that `convert` ?

P.S I don't like `reflection` but need to deal with legacy, which uses it.

Comment: You could use `ClassTag`, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18136667/406435). `def convert[T <: A : ClassTag](a: A) = {val clazz = implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass; if (clazz.isInstance(a)) Some(a.asInstanceOf[T]) else None}`

Comment: @senia Why `Some(a.asInstanceOf[T])` but not just `Some(a)` ?

Comment: type of `a` is `A`, so type of `Some(a)` is `Some[A]`, not `Some[T]`

Comment: @senia Yes, but did not we check that `a` is of type `T` ?

Comment: @senia What if I replace `if (clazz.isInstance(a)) ` with `clazz == a.getClass` ? Does it work the same ?

Comment: No. `a` could be an instance of subtype of `T`. In this case `a` is instance of `T`, but class of `a` is not `T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than `isInstance`, you can use the `ClassTag` in a match expression, which is slightly clearer:

```
def convert[T <: A](a: A)(implicit ct: ClassTag[T]) = a match {
  case ct(t) => Some(t)
  case _ => None
}
```

Comment: Very nice ! Did not know about `ClassTag.unapply`. Thank you.

Comment: That said, you can even write `case t: T => Some(t)`, Scala is smart enough to figure it out.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Did not get it, sorry. Could you give a full example, please ?

Comment: @Michael, sure, see [here](https://gist.github.com/netvl/de3e4388d2e8f2fbc143). In other words, adding `ClassTag` or `TypeTag` context bound allows matching with the bounded generic parameter type safely.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Thank you. Neat and very simple. Probably the best possible solution.