# spark select columns by type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics

I want to have a function to dynamically select spark Dataframe columns by their datatype.

So far, I have created:

```
object StructTypeHelpers {
  def selectColumnsByType[T <: DataType](schem: StructType):Seq[String] = {
    schem.filter(_.dataType.isInstanceOf[T]).map(_.name)
  }

}
```

so that a `StructTypeHelpers. selectColumnsByType[StringType](df.schema)` should work. However, the compiler is warning me that:

```
abstract type T is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

When trying to use:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
def selectColumnsByType[T <: DataType: ClassTag](schem: StructType):Seq[String]
```

it fails with

```
No ClassTag available for T
```

How can I get it to work and compile without the warning?

Comment: Answer will be obvious, just add TypeTag or ClassTag etc https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html as you are not providing information regarding type T in the method.

Comment: But shouldn't this: `T <: DataType: ClassTag` be just that? This failed with: `No ClassTag available for T`

Comment: You have to provide TypeTag / ClassTag info implicitly, this is a bit of the pain, but works nicely

Comment: You mean: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136313/abstract-type-pattern-is-unchecked-since-it-is-eliminated-by-erasure/18136667 ? Still it does not really seem to work just yet.

Comment: No, that's not what I mean, something like def paramInfo[T](x: T)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]), as per my first link, its really should work, sorry, should of put this as the answer :)

Comment: `def selectColumnsByType[T <: DataType](schem: StructType)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]):Seq[String] = {
    schem.filter(_.dataType.isInstanceOf[T]).map(_.name)
  }` would incorporate your advice, but still yields the same warning.

Comment: try something like, I haven't had chance to check if its works, but you can play with typeInfor at run time etc: object StructTypeHelpers {
  def selectColumnsByType[T <: DataType](schem: StructType)(implicit tag:TypeTag[T]):Seq[String] = {
    schem.filter(_.dataType.typeName == tag.tpe.typeSymbol.fullName).map(_.name)
  }
}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The idea is to filter only the columns that have the type that you want and then do select.

```
val df  =  Seq(
  (1, 2, "hello")
).toDF("id", "count", "name")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
def selectByType(colType: DataType, df: DataFrame) = {

  val cols = df.schema.toList
    .filter(x => x.dataType == colType)
    .map(c => col(c.name))
  df.select(cols:_*)

}
val res = selectByType(IntegerType, df)
```

Comment: But this solution  only supports equals, not: `isInstanceOf[columnDataType]`.

Comment: why do you want to use asInstanceOf ?

Comment: Isn't that safer regarding type hierarchy? But you are probably correct that for the primitive types spark supports it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Does anyone know how this can be done in pyspark?

Comment: The particular use case that I have benefits from `isInstanceOf[]` because all precisions of `DecimalType` get included that way. This isn't the normal situation; I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

A literal answer, helped by [How to know if an object is an instance of a TypeTag's type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628379/how-to-know-if-an-object-is-an-instance-of-a-typetags-type), would be this:

```scala
var x = spark.table(...)

import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import scala.reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}
def selectColumnsByType[T <: DataType : ClassTag](schema: StructType):Seq[String] = {
  schema.filter(field => classTag[T].runtimeClass.isInstance(field.dataType)).map(_.name)
}

selectColumnsByType[DecimalType](x.schema)
```

However, this form definitely makes it easier to use:

```scala
var x = spark.table(...)

import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import scala.reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}
class DataFrameHelpers(val df: DataFrame) {
  def selectColumnsByType[T <: DataType : ClassTag](): DataFrame = {
    val cols = df.schema.filter(field => classTag[T].runtimeClass.isInstance(field.dataType)).map(field => col(field.name))
    df.select(cols:_*)
  }    
}

implicit def toDataFrameHelpers(df: DataFrame): DataFrameHelpers = new DataFrameHelpers(df)

x = x.selectColumnsByType[DecimalType]()
```

Note, though, as an earlier answer mentioned -- `isInstanceOf` isn't really appropriate here, although it *is* helpful if you want to get all `DecimalType` columns, regardless of precision. Using the more normal method, you could do the following instead, which also lets you specify multiple types!

```scala
var x = spark.table(...)

import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
class DataFrameHelpers(val df: DataFrame) {
  def selectColumnsByType(dt: DataType*): DataFrame = {
    val cols = df.schema.filter(field => dt.exists(_ == field.dataType)).map(field => col(field.name))
    df.select(cols:_*)
  }    
}

implicit def toDataFrameHelpers(df: DataFrame): DataFrameHelpers = new DataFrameHelpers(df)

x = x.selectColumnsByType(ShortType, DecimalType(38,18))
```